# ArcObjects 10 Java SDK

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, geoprocessing

I am being tasked with converting a AGS geoprocessing toolkit currently written in AO 10 C# SDK to AO 10 Java SDK.  Are there any resources out there which show an end to end example of creating an AGS 10 Java deployable toolkit?

Comment: Bump - No ideas folks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArcGIS web site help has some [sample applications](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#/Samples/00010000042n000000/) for ArcObjects SDK 10 in the Java platform. I hope that helps.

Comment: cheers rk appreciated

Comment: De nada :) Always a pleasure.